# сумма всех натуральных чисел от 1го до n

Tags: математика

объясните пожалуйста почему ?

сумму всех натуральльных чисел от 1го до n можно вычислить как n * (n +1) / 2 .  Например 5
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
или
5*6 /2 = 15

так вот почему это работает ?
5*6 /2 = 15 ?

Comment: А вы попробуйте брать одно число с конца, одно с начала, и посмотрите, чему равна сумма пары, и задумайтесь, сколько таких пар... Например, 1 2 3 4 5 6: 1+6 = 2+5 = 3+4 = 7. А пар 6/2 = 3...

Comment: https://www.yaklass.ru/p/algebra/9-klass/chislovye-posledovatelnosti-progressii-9139/arifmeticheskaia-progressiia-svoistva-arifmeticheskoi-progressii-9141/re-9be60eb3-2e3a-4782-b724-d5bca94395dc

Comment: это к Саватееву) но попытаюсь ответить

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не по теме StackOverflow

Comment: Что значит не по теме, раз есть метка `математика` значит по теме, тут не только программирование можно обсуждать но все остальное даже лингвистику

Comment: @DaniilLoban в описании метки [математика] сказано: `в которых математические задачи решаются средствами программирования.`

Comment: @Danis  эта задача решается средствами программирования. Я решал эту задачу циклом, рекурсией и выше изложенным способом. Так вот, я понимал как работает цикл и рекурсия, но не понимал почему работает  n * (n +1) / 2  . А теперь добрые люди люди мне все разложили по полочкам и я обрел новые полезные знания. А это значит что система выполнила свое главное предназначение. Разве это плохо ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если подумать то сумма `1 + n` будет такая же как и у `2 + n-1`

Пример:

```
1 + 5 = 6
2 + 4 = 6
```

Но в этом ряде еще есть 3 что с ней. Давайте складывать столбиком так:

```
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
```

Каждый столбик равен 6 а столбиков 5 т.е. 5 * 6 = 30
как вижно тут 2 тройки а должна быть одна (и вообще всех чисел по 2), т.е мы должны разделить фигуру на 2
так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поэтому мы делим на 2 и это работает.

Линия просто отделяет дубликаты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Построим треугольник из квадратов:

[image]

его площадь - равно итоговой сумме.

продублируем его:
[image]

развернём и соеденим их:
[image]

в итоге получаем:
[image]

площадь этого прямоугольника: `n*(n+1)`, а т. к. мы использовали две фигуры, то площадь треугольника `n*(n+1)/2`

Похожим образом можно вывести формулу суммы квадратов, только там более сложные манипуляции в 3-х мерном пространстве.

Answer (score 5):

### Творчески

> ```
> s(n) = 1 +   2   +   3   + ... + (n-2) + (n-1) + n
> s(n) = n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... +   3   +   2   + 1
> ```

Сложим попарно:

> ```
> s(n) + s(n) = (1 + n) + (2 + (n-1)) + (3 + (n-2)) + ...
>              ... + ((n-2) + 3) + ((n-1) + 2) + (n + 1)  =
>
> = (1 + n) + (1 + n) + (1 + n) + ... + (1 + n) + (1 + n) + (1 + n) =
>
> = n * (1 + n)
> ```

> ```
> s(n) = n * (n + 1) / 2
> ```

### Строго

Докажем что *s<sub>n</sub> = n(n + 1)/2* для любого целого неотрицательного *n*.

База индукции *n = 0*: *s<sub>0</sub> = 0(0 + 1)/2 = 0*.

Индукционный шаг: пусть формула верна для *s<sub>n-1</sub>*. Вычислим *s<sub>n</sub>*:

*s<sub>n</sub> = s<sub>n-1</sub> + n = (n - 1)((n - 1) + 1)/2 + n = ((n - 1)n + 2n)/2 = (n - 1 + 2)n/2 = n(n + 1)/2*.

Что и требовалось доказать.